# what is regex for string consist of all lowercase vowels in order of a-e-i-o-u where all vowels can occur one or more times?

Tags: java, regex, python-2.7

what is regex for string consist of all lowercase vowels in order of a-e-i-o-u where all vowels can occur one or more times ?

e.g string S="aeeiouu" is accepted but string s2="aiiou" is not accepted.

Comment: what have you tried so far, and what language are you using?

Comment: python 2.7,java,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Java:

```
String pattern = "a+e+i+o+u+";
boolean match = myStr.matches(pattern);
```

Comment: thanks it works properly with java but can you give the solution in python?

Comment: I only know Java, not Phython. Sorry.